# Can i export a specific lines from file to another?

Tags: php

If have a file `A.php` which for sure have some lines, and i want to export or copy specific lines from `A.php` to a new file `B.php`, So the process goes like this (copy lines from x to y in the `A.php`- Create a new file with name `B.php`- Past and save `B.php`).

So if i want to extract lines from 3 to 8 (for example) in the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <?php
    $fname= basename(__FILE__,'php');
    ?>
    <title><?php echo $fname; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a test Page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do this in details if you can?

Comment: put the code you want to re-use into separate file, then `include()` it?

Comment: I don't want to include. I just need to extract some lines and create new file then add these lines into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

This command splits the file into an array of lines:

```
// substitute a local file for the URL
$lines = file('http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php');
echo $lines[0];
// <!DOCTYPE html>
echo $lines[56];
//  <![endif]-->
```

After you have the lines you want you can create a new file and save it.  There are 100 ways to do this. Here is one:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
file_put_contents('fileInCurrentDirectory.php', $lines[3], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

file_put_contents('fileInCurrentDirectory.php', $lines[4], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

file_put_contents('fileInCurrentDirectory.php', $lines[5], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: But i want to generate the new file automatically. Extract line and create the new file and import these lines to it automatically

Comment: Thanks, i worked my mind and finally i have reached what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to convert the file into an array of lines, then [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the lines you want and finally [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to export to the new file. Like this:

```
function A2B($a,$b,$from,$to){
    $f = file($a,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $n = array_slice($f,($from-1),($to-$from+1));
    file_put_contents($b,implode("\n",$n));
}
```

and call it like

```
A2B("a.php","b.php",3,6);
```